# Laravel with SQL server 2008 throw "Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, laravel-4

I am using laravel 4.1 with SQL Server 2008

I created a model based on Eloquent orm with timestamp:

```
class Attendance extends \Eloquent {

protected $table = 'Attendance';

public function users(){return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'Users_Attendance', 'user_id', 'attendance_id');}

}
```

When I try to insert new fields:

```
public function postAttendanceUsers() {
    $attendance = new Attendance;
    $attendance->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $attendance->save();
}
```

Display the following error:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
>       Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>       (SQL: insert into [Attendance] ([user_id], [updated_at], [created_at]) values (40, 2015-08-27 12:28:42.000, 2015-08-27 12:28:42.000))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a new method with the following format:

```
 /**
 * Get the format for database stored dates.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDateFormat() {
    return 'Y-d-m H:i:s';
}
```

I hope somebody be useful

Comment: Great answer! For those who can't change this piece of code for business reasons or this setting works in some environments, but not in others, I recommend to read my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the date values should have single quotes around them...like '20151130'

Or to be more specific:

```
insert into [Attendance] ([user_id], [updated_at], [created_at]) values (40, '2015-08-27 12:28:42.000', '2015-08-27 12:28:42.000')
```

You could test it with SQL directly, using a refined date:

```
insert into [Attendance] ([user_id], [updated_at], [created_at]) values (40, '20150827', '20150827')
```

If that fails, there are serious compatibility issues with the installation and default language (collation) settings in SQL

Comment: I try but threw the same error.
The problem is laravel or I think so because Eloquent is responsible for the insert

Comment: Is your PC, or where your SQL server site - using a language other than English?

Comment: Finally I had to transform the DateTime format when values be inserted. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

I use Laravel and SQL Server. Try adding this code to your Eloquent base model. Laravel tries to insert milliseconds and SQL Server doesn't like it

```
/**
 * Get the format for database stored dates.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDateFormat()
{
    return 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
}

/**
 * Convert a DateTime to a storable string.
 * SQL Server will not accept 6 digit second fragment (PHP default: see getDateFormat Y-m-d H:i:s.u)
 * trim three digits off the value returned from the parent.
 *
 * @param  \DateTime|int  $value
 * @return string
 */
public function fromDateTime($value)
{
    return substr(parent::fromDateTime($value), 0, -3);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work :(
Which data type do you work datetime or datetime2?

Comment: Me too but with your code laravel gave me the same error :'(

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, this issue can be fixed in any case making sure an unambiguous date format is used (indepedent from the region) in the commented `getDateFormat` function, such as:

`YMD H:i:s` or `Y-M-DTH:i:s.mmm`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using custom types in Doctrine with Symfony. Like others answers, I had a class that specified the DateTime format in which a DateTime object is formated to work with the DB. In my case was `Y-d-m H:i:s.000` and worked perfectly in production, but not in my local environment, throwing *Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value*.

The solution came up changing the default language **for the user** that Symfony (in your case Laravel) uses to connect to the DB: in production was `Spanish` and my setting local was `English`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/755908/7058363) helped me to make the change and fix the problem.

**Note**: using [SET DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) didn't solve my problem, even changing the language on every database.