# How to apply spanish dateformat for single database not for all databases in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to apply Spanish dateformat for my database not for all databases in SQL Server. For the remaining databases, I have to maintain the US-english date format.

How can we do this without affecting other databases?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `SET DATEFORMAT` syntax to set the dateformat when you are executing your query.

Also note that [SET DATEFORMAT](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/28/sql-server-introduction-and-example-for-dateformat-command/) is used only for formatting the dates, it will not change the format in which the dates are stored.

Comment: thanks...its working for me.

Comment: @sam:- You are welcome!

Comment: when my application dealing with different countries not only spain, like canada, australia,japan etc..then how can I set format for the respective country? I am using insert query from front end. not using any procedures.

Comment: @sam:- In my opinion you dont have to set the format everytime for a specific country. Instead you can set the date format in your database and then using the frontend you can change the format using your code and then insert it into the database.

Comment: @sam - write your insert query to use *parameters*. Assuming e.g. C#, you give it a `DateTime` parameter, ADO.Net and SQL Server already know how to convert between .NET's `DateTime` and SQL Server's `datetime`. No strings are ever involved and there are, therefore, no formatting issues to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this answer has to be a comment.

This question is a duplicate of this: [Changing dateformat on a SQL Server DB and not on whole server to dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755849/changing-dateformat-on-a-sql-server-db-and-not-on-whole-server-to-dd-mm-yyyy)